# Where is best place to save UnitOfWork for Web Api?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

Simple question really.

I have a large number of OData controllers, which call their repositries to save/update/delete data. At the end of these operations I am calling a UnitOfWork to save.

```
    public async Task<Foo> Post(Foo entity)
    {
        repository.Insert(entity);

        await UnitOfWork.Save();

        return entity;
    }

    public async Task<Foo> Put([FromODataUri] int key, Foo entity)
    {
        await repository.Update(entity, key);

        await UnitOfWork.Save();

        return entity;
    }
```

However I have begun using batch operations, so would be better if the UnitOfWork was saved at the end of the series of operations, rather than on each one. Where should I be saving?

Comment: Typically one chooses to use a Unit-Of-Work pattern specifically to allow them to 'collect' a related series of updates and then Save them all at once.

Answer (score 0):

> I have begun using batch operations, so would be better if the UnitOfWork was saved at the end of the series of operations, rather than on each one. Where should I be saving?

1. You could either pass in all the values for the batch operation. E.g. a list of Foo. Perform operations on the list and then save.
2. You could take in a boolean that indicates whether to Save the batch operation.
3. Or you could expose a Save method and only call UnitOfWork.Save() from there. This would require changing the lifetime of your UnitOfWork in your Autofac registrations though which could cause undesirable behavior for non-batch operations. I'd stay away from this option for that reason.

To me, the first option seems like the best usability-wise.

Comment: Hm. Was just hoping I could do a $batch operation and have it only commit once at the end of the transaction.